# Issue on unzip cmd in windows

Tags: windows, git-bash, unzip

I have a peculiar behaviour on unzipping through git bash in Windows 10. The result is that for some files "a.exe" is considerered the same as "a". However in some other cases this is not the case. The command I execute is:

```
unzip -l -qq myzip.zip | awk '{print $4}'

mydir/
mydir/glassfish4/
mydir/glassfish4/mq/
mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/
mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqbridgemgr.exe
mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqadmin
mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqbridgemgr
mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqadmin.exe
```

if I do the following:

```
  unzip myzip.zip
    
  creating: mydir/
  creating: mydir/glassfish4/
  creating: mydir/glassfish4/mq/
  creating: mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/
  inflating: mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqbridgemgr.exe
  inflating: mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqadmin
  replace mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqbridgemgr? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
  inflating: mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqbridgemgr
  inflating: mydir/glassfish4/mq/bin/imqadmin.exe
```

As you notice because "imqadmin" is before "imqadmin.exe" there is no issue. But for "imqbridgemgr.exe" which is before "imqbridgemgr" there is.

In linux I don't have such a weird behaviour. The same if I unzip it from GUI in windows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only working around on Windows is:

```
powershell -command "Expand-Archive -LiteralPath \"$(cygpath -aw /path/to/zip)\" -DestinationPath ."
```

as in MSYS2 the CYGWIN=notransparent_exe setting has been removed in [cygwin/cygwin@9bf7c7e](https://github.com/cygwin/cygwin/commit/9bf7c7e96cf97fb10054775cfc84a92b4f45dea0) and it is always on.